# How can I avoid stuck processes?

Tags: php, mysqli, prepared-statement

If I comment out the following code from the page, it works fine.
But if the code in, processes stuck and the site slows down and I get  500 server error.

If someone click on a series datasheet it loads the episodes.
And if choose an episode and click on it loads the online links and scroll down

```
<a name="online"></a>
<br><h4 id="b" style="padding-left: 15px;">Episodes:</h4>
<div class="blog-pagenat-wthree">
<ul>
<?php
$query = "SELECT episode FROM episodes WHERE seriesid = ? ORDER BY episode LIMIT 1";
$stmt = $conn->prepare($query);
$stmt->bind_param('i', $id);
$stmt->execute();
$stmt->bind_result($firstepisode);
$stmt->fetch();
$stmt->close();

$query = "SELECT episode FROM episodes WHERE seriesid = ?";
$stmt = $conn->prepare($query);
$stmt->bind_param('i', $id);
$stmt->execute();
$stmt->store_result();
$allepisode = $stmt->num_rows;
$stmt->close();

$title2 = str_replace(array("'"), array("\'"), $title);
$title3 = sanitize($title2);
$season = explode(". season", $title2);
$season2 = explode(" - ", $season[0]);

for($i=$firstepisode; $i<=$allepisode; $i++)
{
    echo "<li><a href='mysite/".$id."/".$title3."-series/".$i."-episode#online'>".$i."</a></li> ";
}
?>
</ul>
</div>
```

I tried to comment out just the code which loads the links but I think this part case the stuck processes.

Comment: You have no open or closing PHP tags between the PHP and the HTML

Comment: Check your web server's error log for the exact error, but I am going to guess that your `for()` loop is never completing because `$allepisode` has a bad value. That would cause high server load and eventually a 500 error.

Comment: @Qirel sorry I just forgot it, these are in the code

Comment: @MichaelBerkowski The `for()` loop is ends I think because the episodes lists correctly.

Comment: Where does the `$id` param come from? Could it be `null`? Also, as @MichaelBerkowski stated, `$allepisode` doesn't look good. What if `$firstepisode` is greater than the number of episodes? This could be caused by bad data.